# The best way to get data from my blog

Tags: java, android, web-crawler

How is the best way to get data from own blog based on HTML?

I have simply blog with news. Each news is in div with class "news". I would like every hour to check on my application on Android whether news appeared. I dont want use RSS and XML.

How is the best way for this?

Comment: Why do you not want to use RSS/XML? I want to get 250 miles, but I don't want to take a car, bus, train, or plane.

Comment: I dont want use RSS/XML because i am learning Java and Android. I would like make it with parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`JSoup`](http://jsoup.org/) is the solution.

> jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides
>   a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the
>   best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.
>
> jsoup implements the WHATWG HTML5 specification, and parses HTML to
>   the same DOM as modern browsers do.

I believe [this](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) will serve as a starting point:

```
String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("a").first();

String text = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"
String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "http://example.com/"
String linkText = link.text(); // "example""

String linkOuterH = link.outerHtml(); 
    // "<a href="http://example.com"><b>example</b></a>"
String linkInnerH = link.html(); // "<b>example</b>"
```

**Update:**
As suggested by `hexafraction`, you can use RSS. It is a format for regularly-changing delivering web content like news, etc. and is commonly used by many websites to help their users stay up to date. It delivers information about your content, like the title, description, link, etc., in an XML format that you can parse to display data to the user.

Writing an XML parser to parse RSS feed will be much easier than parsing the HTML using `JSoup`. [This about.com article](http://webdesign.about.com/od/rss/a/link_rss_feed.htm) will help you with adding RSS to your website.

Comment: In my opinion, the OP is experiencing the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). While this is correct, I'd advise including some more details on why RSS/XML may be a better idea, and a paragraph or so on where to look to implement it.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to address the OP a bit better. +1 added.